# DataGridView call function when user end editing new row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to build a windows application using VB.NET
In my app I have a datagridview and user can edit/delete/update row.

I am trying to figure out how to detect when user end editing row sperating new rows and updated row.

I am trying to use

```
    MyDataGridView_RowLeave(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles MyDataGridView.RowLeave
```

In rowLeave I can't figure out how to detect if it is a new row or updating existing row.

Comment: Is the grid bound to a `DataTable`?

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes it is

Answer (score 0):

As your grid is bound to a `DataTable`, the `RowState` of the underlying `DataRow` can provide the information you want.

```
Dim gridRow = MyDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex)
Dim rowView = DirectCast(gridRow.DataBoundItem, DataRowView)
Dim tableRow = rowView.Row

Select Case tableRow.RowState
    Case DataRowState.Unchanged
        '...
    Case DataRowState.Added
        '...
    Case DataRowState.Modified
        '...
    Case DataRowState.Deleted
        '...
End Select
```